# Количество чисел в смешанном массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

**Задание:** Напишите функцию countOfNumbers, которая принимает массив arr как аргумент и возвращает количество элементов, которые являются числами. Массив arr может состоять из чисел, строк и булевых (логичесих) величин.

Примеры:

функция countOfNumbers([2, 'a', 5, true, 'b', 1, 'c']) должна возвратить 3 (3 числа: 2, 5, 1);

функция countOfNumbers([true, false, 'abc']) должна возвратить 0;

```
function countOfNumbers(arr){
let count = 0;
if (!arr.length) {
return 0;
}
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
if (arr[i] === Number) {
count = count + 1; 
}
}
return count;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема:** Не понимаю, как прописать в функции, что мне нужни только числа.

Comment: typeof(a[i]) === number

Comment: Точнее `typeof(a[i]) === 'number'`

Comment: @vsemozhebuty спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 3):

Наверняка есть нюансы, но работает в большинстве случаев:

```js
function countOfNumbers(arr) {
  return arr.filter(item => Number.isFinite(item)).length;
}

alert(countOfNumbers(['7', 2.5, 'a', 0, true, 'b', 1, 'c', Infinity, NaN, -Infinity, null]))
```

Comment: `isFinite("7")` дает true. А там строка)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME: думаю, что Вы ошибаетесь. Попробуйте вывести отфильтрованный массив в консоль - результатом будет `[2.5, 0, 1]`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME: просто не путайте глобальную функцию `isFinite()` с методом `Number.isFinite()` - [последний не преобразует типы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function countOfNumbers(arr){
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           // console.log(arr[i])
           if ( Number.isInteger(arr[i])||parseFloat(arr[i])) {
            count ++
        }
        }
        return count;
    }
      alert(countOfNumbers([2.5 ,'a', 5.6, true, 'b', 1, 'c']) )
```

Comment: К сожалению, не будет работать с нецелыми числами (они, кажется, должны приниматься).

Comment: if ( Number.isInteger(arr[i])||parseFloat(arr[i])) {
                count ++
            }

Comment: Изменил , проверьте

Comment: А вот `parseFloat` будет принимать строковое представление чисел.

Comment: Думаю, тут только typeof подходит. Если же нужно отбросить NaN, тогда ещё проверить `Number.isNaN()`.

Comment: Можно ещё использовать `Number.isFinite()`, если бесконечность не допускается в массиве.

Answer (score 0):

if **(typeof(arr[i]) === 'number')** { count = count + 1; }

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]